# Simple spring application terminates unless there is a call to Thread.sleep(...)

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, apache-camel

I am seeing some strange behaviour with a very simple Java application which uses Spring and Apache Camel.

I have defined the below spring bean in my application context:

```
<camel:camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <camel:endpoint id="incoming" uri="activemq:queue:${myqueue}?jmsMessageType=Text" />
    <camel:route id="handleIncomingEvents" autoStartup="true" trace="true">
        <camel:from ref="incoming" />
        <camel:bean ref="transform" method="toEvent" />
        <camel:bean ref="eventConsumer" method="consumeEvent" />
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

This is a camel context with a single route. As far as I know, when this the bean is created, a new thread will be started which listens for incoming messages and routes them to my eventConsumer.

My starting point for the application is simply:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {     
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
}
```

The problem is:

When I run the simple application above, the log output shows that the camel context and route are initialised successfully, but then the application terminates immediately.

However, if I add a Thread.sleep(1000) after initialising the application-context, the application never terminates. This is the behaviour I expected, since there is a new thread created which listens for incoming messages.

Why do I need to call Thread.sleep to achieve the expected behaviour?

This is clearly not the correct way to do it - what am I doing wrong?

---

Edit[1]: There is nothing unusual in the logs. The below log output is produced both with and without the call to Thread.sleep(1000).

```
29 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler - OSGi environment not detected.
1473 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.9.0 (CamelContext: camelContext) is starting
1474 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.ManagementStrategyFactory - JMX enabled. Using ManagedManagementStrategy.
1541 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy - StatisticsLevel at All so enabling load performance statistics
1618 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Found 3 packages with 15 @Converter classes to load
1637 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Loaded 168 core type converters (total 168 type converters)
1650 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader - Found 2 packages with 3 @Converter classes to load
1651 [main] WARN org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Overriding type converter from: StaticMethodTypeConverter: public static org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination org.apache.activemq.camel.converter.ActiveMQConverter.toDestination(java.lang.String) to: StaticMethodTypeConverter: public static org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination org.apache.camel.component.activemq.ActiveMQConverter.toDestination(java.lang.String)
1664 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Loaded additional 3 type converters (total 171 type converters) in 0.025 seconds
1946 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: handleIncomingEvents started and consuming from: Endpoint[activemq://queue:myqueue?jmsMessageType=Text]
1958 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
1958 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.9.0 (CamelContext: camelContext) started in 0.485 seconds
```

---

Edit[2]: I was using this ActiveMQ configuration:

```
<bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="maximumActive" value="500" />
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
            <property name="closeTimeout" value="10" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfigRetry" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="activemqretry" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfigRetry" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What happens if, after ApplicationContext code in your `main()` method, you add the following: `context.getBean(org.apache.camel.CamelContext.class);` and take out that `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have an effect. The application terminates immediately, straight after camel and the route have been started.

Comment: This should work without `sleep`. Is there something special in the log?

Comment: Please see my updated post, I have included the log output.

Comment: It sounds like the worker thread is a daemon thread, or there's a race condition between a non-daemon thread getting started and main returning. Is there a object in the context for the listener you can block on until shutdown?

Comment: If it was a daemon thread, then wouldn't the application still terminate after the Thread.sleep(1000)? I'm not sure if there's anything I could block on. For now, I am using the activemq configuration in Peter's answer, which doesn't have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide your ActiveMQ settings in your question. For tests, I use following setup:

```
<!-- This creates an embedded ActiveMQ broker -->
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" useJmx="true" persistent="false">
    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </transportConnectors>
</broker>

<!-- Lets connect the Camel ActiveMQ component to the embedded broker -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>
```

If successfully configured, you should see following log:

```
[ActiveMQ Task-1] FailoverTransport INFO  Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
```

Perhaps, you may try this setup and test if it works.

Comment: Thanks, with this configuration I don't need the Thread.sleep. I posted the configuration I was using above... still not sure what was wrong with it!

Comment: Did you try to set a higher `closeTimeout`?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't seem to make a difference. Maybe I'll just stick with your configuration, I don't think I need a pooled connection factory for now. It would be nice to know what was causing the issue though!

Comment: I'm still not sure what the correct way to do this is. With your ActiveMQ config, it works fine, but I have a warning "Resource leak: 'context' is never closed". To fix this, I add a context.close(); at the end of my main method. This removes the warning, but the application now terminates immediately again. So - what is the correct way to initialise a camel route via Spring, and leave the route running indefinitely?

Comment: I thought adding the daemon=true parameter to the transportConnector would prevent ActiveMQ from shutting down when the application context is closed, but it doesn't...

Comment: I found the correct way to do it - see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the correct way to do this is to start the camel route as an independent application:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.apache.camel.spring.Main camelMain = new org.apache.camel.spring.Main();
        camelMain.setApplicationContextUri("application-context.xml");
        camelMain.run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same things happened to me. In my application `Camel` is embedded in `Spring`. To investigate further I registered a `StartupListener` to the Spring context, with a piece of code that spits out the list of threads just after the `CamelContext` is started. Here's the result...

```
44:09.166 INFO  [main ] Thread 'main' in group 'main' is daemon ? false.
44:09.167 INFO  [main ] Thread 'TIBCO EMS TCPLink Reader (Server-80)' in group 'main' is daemon ? true.
44:09.167 INFO  [main ] Thread 'Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[test.treds_2.input]' in group 'main' is daemon ? true.
```

Now... as you can see there are two threads related to `Camel`: the `TIBCO EMS TCPLink Reader` one and the `Camel (camel-1)` one. As you can see, at the end of the log line, the two threads are marked as **daemon**. This means that when the main thread finishes, all the other Camel threads do not prevent the app to stop because they are running as deamon. In your case, probably, the `Thread.sleep(1000)` allows some other not daemon thread to kick in, thus avoiding the app to shut down.

This is not a solution to your problem but tries to answer to your question:

> Why do I need to call Thread.sleep to achieve the expected behaviour?